# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' - when I'm removing duplicate elements from a sorted linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

```
def listDistinct(self): 
        if self.isListEmpty():
            return self.failureValue
        else:
            currentNode = self.head
            while currentNode is not None:
                previousNode = currentNode
                currentNode = currentNode.next
                if currentNode.data == previousNode.data: # Line of Error
                    previousNode.next = currentNode.next
```

How to get the **last node** of the linked list get **compared with its previous node.**
Only the last element is not removed, even though it is duplicate.

Comment: I'm guessing this is caused because your while loop checks that `currentNode` is something, but inside the loop, your code assigns `currentNode` to `currentNode.next`... I guess you could change your condition on your while loop to be `while currentNode.next is not None:`...

Comment: @EdWard That is wrong. `while currentNode.next` will break when self.head is `None`.

Comment: @Poojan yeah you're right...

Comment: Yes, I did `currentNode.next`, but it doesn't compare the last node. It exits the loop before comparing the last node.

Answer (score 0):

- You are getting error because you are reaching end of linked list. And after doing next you are not checking for `None` value. One way to handle this it to check if `currentNode` has next value or not in `while` condition.

```
def listDistinct(self): 
        if self.isListEmpty():
            return self.failureValue
        else:
            currentNode = self.head
            while currentNode and currentNode.next:
                previousNode = currentNode
                currentNode = currentNode.next
                if currentNode.data == previousNode.data: # Line of Error
                    previousNode.next = currentNode.next
```

- Try this implementation it should work. Above implementation have logical error. Where it will skip elements when 3 or more same numbers come.

```
def listDistinct(self): 
        if self.isListEmpty():
            return self.failureValue
        else:
            currentNode = self.head
            while currentNode:
                nextNode = currentNode.next
                while nextNode and nextNode.data == currentNode.data:
                    currentNode.next = nextNode.next
                    nextNode = nextNode.next
                currentNode = nextNode
```

Comment: it does compare. When your current node is second last node. It will compare. And when your currentNode reaches last node it will breakout. Can you post an example where its failing?

Comment: It doesn't compare the last node.
For example, if the list is 1,2,2,3,3,3 the result is 1,2,3,3. Where it ignores the last comparison

Comment: What does it mean? Could you please point me, where my implementation is wrong.